# Ionic TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at first time i click save button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

my problem is the first time that i click the save button i get that error, however if i click the button once again the code works fine, so i can't understand what is happening why undefined?

here is my code:

```js
$scope.getProfileContent = function(value){
                            Words.getProfileContent(value).then(function(detalle){
                                if (!detalle) {
                                    $scope.profileContent = {
                                        title: null
                                        
                                    };  
      
                                }else{
                                
                                 $scope.profileContent = detalle;
                             
                                }
                                 
                            });   

        };


if ($scope.salvo === true ){
                $scope.noSavedPopup();
            }else if($scope.editWordRow.title===null || $scope.imgURI===null || $scope.tempSrc===null || $scope.tempSrc2===null)
            {
                $scope.nullPopup();
                console.log($scope.editWordRow.title);
                console.log($scope.imgURI);
                console.log($scope.tempSrc);
                console.log($scope.tempSrc2);
             }else {
                
                $scope.getProfileContent(content);
                if ($scope.profileContent.title===null) {
                    
                    console.log("El title es : " + $scope.profileContent.title);
                                
                }else{
                    
                    console.log("El title es : " + $scope.profileContent.title +"y esta en BD");
                    
                }
                 
                 
                 
             }
```

services.js

```js
 self.getProfileContent = function(content) {
    var parameters = [content];
    return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM learners WHERE title = (?)", parameters)
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getById(result);
      });
  };
```

view.html

```js
 <div class="text-center"><input style="font-size: 18px !important; text-align: right !important; font-weight: bold !important;" type="text" ng-model="editWordRow.title">
            <hr style="border-color: #11c1f3 !important; margin-right: 20px !important;margin-left: 20px !important;">
        </div>
```

this is driving me crazy, regards!!!

Comment: Some of you code can be shortened. Expressions like if ($scope.salvo === true ) can be shortened to if($scope.salvo).

Comment: i think you should reformat your code. you make it hard for us to try to answer because it is hard to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, because `getProfileContent` is no synchronous function. You are mixing up synchronous and asynchronous calls. `getProfileContent` in your services.js returns a promise. And you are handling it correctly at the beginning of your code:

```
Words.getProfileContent(value).then(function(detalle){
```

Your scope function however is a synchronous function. So the reason why `profileContent` is undefined is, that the promise you call has not been resolved when you call it the first time. There are several options now how to solve this, I would suggest you make your synchronous function async by doing:

```
$scope.getProfileContent = function(value){
  //notice the return on the next line
  return Words.getProfileContent(value).then(function(detalle){
    if (!detalle) {
      $scope.profileContent = {
        title: null
      };  
    }else{
      $scope.profileContent = detalle;
    }
    return detalle;
  });   
};
```

You will then return a promise and in your later code be able to only continue when it is resolved like:

```
       $scope.getProfileContent(content).then(function(detalle) {
        if (detalle.title===null) {
            console.log("El title es : " + $scope.profileContent.title);

        }else{
            $scope.profileContent = detalle;
            console.log("El title es : " + $scope.profileContent.title +"y esta en BD");

        }
```

You can read this intro on [angular promises and traps](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i tried your code, now title is undefined always not only the first time, in this line  `$scope.getProfileContent(content).then(function(detalle) {
        if (detalle.title===null) {` on evaluation of detalle.title===null

Comment: I think things are getting mixed up. analyze your variables.  my function should work. but if detalle.title === null then it is because your Words.getProfileContent returns a detalle with null title.

Answer (score 0):

The object that the field "title" belongs to is undefined at the time the code is run that throws the exception.

You need to make sure the code defining the object is run before you try to check the title field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the aswer, look at this piece of code  `$scope.getProfileContent(content);
                if ($scope.profileContent.title===null) {` Just before the condition i did call getProfileContent so I'm defining the object, the courious thing is, the object is undifined just at the first time, the second time i click the save button, it works...